# Turbo C++ tools produce "No DOS extensions in the DPMI server" when compiling and linking code

Tags: c++, assembly, tasm, dosbox, turbo-c++

I'm trying to link a .cpp file and a .asm file, this is my code:

**factorial1.cpp**

```
#include<iostream.h>;
#include<conio.h>;

int n;

extern int factorial();
void main(){
    char tl;    
    L1: 
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\n n: "; cin>>n;
        cout<<"\n n factorial: "<<n<<" is: "<<factorial();
        cout<<"\n continue (y/n)?";
        tl=getch();
        if(tl=='y') goto L1;

}
```

**factorial2.asm**

```
.MODEL large
.DATA 
    EXTRN _n:word
.CODE
    PUBLIC @factorial$qv
    @factorial$qv PROC
        mov cx,_n
        mov ax,1
        cmp cx,2
        jb L3

    L2: mul cx
        loop L2   
    L3: ret     
    @factorial$qv ENDP
END
```

Then, I use this command in to compile the codes:
`\Compiler\BIN\TCC -ml -I\Compiler\INCLUDE -L\Compiler\LIB factorial1.cpp factorial2.asm`

I got the .obj files but dosbox show the error:

> no DOS extensions in the DPMI server

how can I fix that error?

**EDIT:** My full output:
[image: My full output]

I'm using tcc 3.0, tasm version 4.1 and tlink version 7.0

**EDIT 2**
I tried TLINK 3.01 and 5.0 now I got this
[image]

**EDIT 3**
I changed `extern int factorial();` to `extern "C" int factorial();` in cpp file and `@factorial$qv` to `_factorial` in asm file. I compiled it with no error now. But when I use TLINK to link 2 obj file, I got this error:
[image]

Comment: Make sure that you don't mix up the code size. A DPMI executable is usually 32-bit, but that `asm` file looks like 16-bit code.

Comment: @DarkAtom so if my code is 16-bit, how could I run it? I've only been learning about this for over 2 weeks so I still don't understand much

Comment: If you just started two weeks ago, is there a particular reason you decided to study technology that has been obsolete for 25 years?  Not that there's anything wrong with it, just ... are you aware?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I absolutely aware of this language's difficulty. I really don't want to learn it either. But my university requires a mandatory course in system programming using Assembly, so I have to study it.

Comment: I suspect one of the tools you are using is expecting DPMI services. You mention it generated OBJ files. Did it create both a FACTORIAL1.OBJ and FACTORIAL2.OBJ? I assume it didn't create an FACTORIAL1.EXE file? What version of TCC are you using? Same question for TLINK (Turbo Link) and TASM (Turbo assembler). When you compile/link everything with TCC the version for TCC, Turbo Link and Turbo assembler should be displayed in the output. Might be easier if you add to your question the full output of the TCC command you are running (Not just the error).

Comment: Unrelated: you can try tagging your `factorial` declaration as `extern "C"` so you can just define a `factorial` symbol instead of the awkwards `@factorial$qv`

Comment: @KienNguyen I don't have any experience with TCC but it seems that it produces 32-bit code meant to run under the [DOS Protected Mode Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Protected_Mode_Interface). You should either tell your compiler to produce 16-bit code (if it has an option for that) or write your factorial function using 32-bit Assembly.

Comment: "a mandatory course in system programming using Assembly". The questionable part isn't that you are studying Assembly language (that's a very fun subject to study, it teaches you a lot about computers), but that you are studying 16-bit x86 ASM, which hasn't been widely used since the beginning of the 21st century. What's your university thinking? Why not the currently used 32-bit or 64-bit? Yes, DOS assembly is fun as a hobby or recreational project, but there's no real reason to teach it anymore.

Comment: Just run `tlink` without arguments. Does it display the same DPMI error? If yes, then it's a tooling issue, try tunning CWSDPMI (installed separately) first.

Comment: Could you be using the wrong compiler? This is Borland Turbo C++, obviously, but the Tiny C compiler is also sometimes referred to as TCC.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I edited my post with my output and version of TCC, TLink and TASM. Can you see it again?

Comment: @pts No, tlink work normally

Comment: I was the first to point out that this is a tools issue and not the running of your program. I don't have those particular versions. It does appear your TLINK requires DPMI. I have an environment of TCC 3.00, Turbo Assembler 3.0 and Turbo Link 2.0 and it builds in DosBox without an issue and I am also able to run your program. You could look at finding an older version of Turbo Link (would come with TASM or Turbo C++) and see if you have a better result. Where did you get your TCC/TASM/TLINK build environment? Was it provided by your course? Is there a link online to download it?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried with TLINK 3.01 and 5.0, both give me new error: `Error: Undefined symbol factorial() in module gt1.cpp`

Comment: At least the DPMI issue is resolved. That's good. The error you are getting now is because there is some problem between the decorated name for for function factorial in the ASM file being used and the decorated name used  by CPP.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I didn't change anything in cpp and asm file. I also provided the error screenshot

Comment: Okay, try this. Modify the CPP file to use `extern "C" int factorial();` instead of `extern int factorial();`. Then in the ASM file replace all occurrences of `@factorial$qv` with `_factorial` and then try to rebuild everything.

Comment: "Assembly language" isn't just one single language.  There are different architectures like AArch64 and RISC-V, and different OSes with different system calls (e.g. Linux system calls are usable directly from hand-written assembly pretty easily, like DOS, except with different calling conventions and a different set calls that exist.  e.g. there aren't special calls for a "console", that's also just reading and writing a file.)

Comment: x86 DOS assembly language is obsolete.  16-bit real mode with segmentation is an interesting case-study in CPU architecture once you know the basics from learning something simpler, like a flat memory model in 32 or 64-bit mode x86, or a different ISA like RISC-V.  And 32-bit protected mode is also interesting in the way they extended the ISA to turn segments into descriptors, but is yet another level of complexity.  Hopefully DPMI hides that and you just have a flat memory model, but if so, why use DOS at all instead of Windows or Linux?

Comment: That means you're stuck using ancient tools like TASM and Turbo C++ that probably have less nice warnings for syntax errors and bugs than modern tools. (I realize this is a question for your instructors, not something you can change if you're taking a course that uses obsolete DOS stuff.)  Looking at asm output from a modern compiler is a good way to learn more about asm.  e.g. Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)” is nice.

Comment: @PeterCordes : He's not creating a DPMI application (his command line tells me that). His command and his code create a 16-bit DOS EXE. In fact his code built and ran here as expected (I just use different versions of TASM/TLINK). The issue simply is he's using a tool chain with a tool (TLINK) that doesn't play nice for some reason in DosBox. There are some old articles regarding some of the later Borland tools having issues with DPMI.

Comment: Ok thanks, so an inconvenient toolchain.  And yet another university course teaching obsolete nd over-complicated x86-16 segmentation when assembly language alone presents enough challenges for beginners.   This would be a non-problem if writing 32 or 64-bit code for Linux, where you'll have `ld` and GAS already, and `nasm` and `gdb` are easy to install.  And you have excellent debugging tools like `strace` and `gdb`.  It's really unfortunate that schools are wasting student's time with unnecessary complications like DOS and decades-old proprietary toolchains; dead-end experience.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I did like you suggested and it compiled with no error, but when I try to link objs file with TLINK I got new errors.

Comment: Why are you using TLINK directly? Why not use TCC to assemble/compile and link all in one step like what you did originally? If you invoke TLINK directly you have to specify the C++ and startup libraries manually (that is why those symbols can't be found). If you run it through TCC to do it all for you, TCC will automatically pass the right libraries to the TLINK command line.

Comment: Actually, you appear to be building everything with TCC and then running TLINK after. The linker gets run automatically when you use TCC to compile/assemble/link. After the TCC command there should have been a GT1.EXE program in the directory to run.

Comment: @MichaelPetch understood! I now can run the program. Thank you very much. You helped me alot